# Огонь - огниво - огненный - огнь

Tags: словообразование

Огонь - огниво - огненный - огнь

По сути - **огниво** - **огненный** - исходные от слова **огнь**!

Почему слово **огнь** вышло из употребления?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Древнерусская и старославянская форма слова **огнь** употреблялась в литературе до начала 19 века (Карамзин, Крылов). К тому времени уже более двух веков существовала и конкурировала с ней форма **огонь**: в сочетании согласных ГН развился дополнительный слоговый гласный О, под влиянием первого. Слово *огнь* осталось в церковнославянском языке, в текстах библейских книг; также оно возможно в торжественной поэзии "под старину" (*огнь священный*).

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Слово **огонь** происходит от санскритского слова **агни**. В русском языке добрая половина слов – это выходцы из **санскрита**. На мой взгляд, трансформация слова **огнь** была произведена для удаления от первоисточника. А, вообще, читая книги на старорусском языке, я заметил, что ранее речь была более краткой, но ёмкой: «Иду на вы!», «Мой меч тяжелее – почему кошелёк легче!?» Ранее было **ся**, ныне – **себя**: отсюда помыть**ся**, забыть**ся**. Вопрос этот, конечно же, гораздо глубже, чем выглядит на первый взгляд: здесь и философия, и религия, и даже политика. До христианства Русь была ведической и волхвы – хранители ведических традиций использовали язык-первоисточник Вед, так же, как в медицине до сих пор оперируют терминами из латыни. С приходом христианства следовало поломать эти традиции, для того и реформировались слова, письменность. Октябрьская революция так же принесла свои новшества и изменения в язык. Сейчас мы можем наблюдать некоторые манипуляции языком на Украине (простите, но я привык говорить не **в**, а **на**). Для чего это делается можете сами поразмыслить, наблюдая за происходящими там событиями.

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый комментарий!

Comment: >В русском языке добрая половина слов – это выходцы из санскрита.

Не совсем так. Можно сказать, почти с точностью до наоборот.

.

В русском языке ЕСТЬ слова похожие на санскрит. Потому эти языки и относятся к ОДНОЙ языковой семье -- индоевропейской. И ещё туда относятся латынь, греческий и др.  Во ВСЕХ языках этой семьи ЕСТЬ похожие слова. 

.

Предки индусов (индийцев, исповедующих индуизм, ведическую религию) отделились от европейцев несколько тысяч лет назад. И у них есть слова, похожие на старославянские, древнегреческие, латинские, литовские...

Comment: Извините, но манипуляций с языком никаких нет - есть оттенки восприятия. Считает человек, что это страна - использует предлог "в". Полагает, что это просто территория (тем более, что в пользу этого говорит привычка, базирующаяся на недавней истории) - и используется "на".

Comment: @Tom d_Cat Сибирь у нас как, страна?Почему же "в Сибири"?А Куба как же?Не просто страна, а государство.Почему же "на Кубе"?Была ли Малороссия страной?Но мы до сих пор говорим "в Малороссии".Не слыхали ль Вы выражение,несколько устаревшее - "на Москве"?(Имеется в виду государство Московское).А про Русь как говорят? Ведь Русь-то всегда страна,Киевская она,Галицкая или Ростовско-Суздальская.Но(только)- "на Руси", и никак иначе.Мы говорим "на Филиппинах",но "в Индонезии"(а это ж страны,государства).И выходит-нет такого правила, о котором Вы пытаетесь заявить.Просто ТАК СЛОЖИЛОСЬ в русском языке.

Comment: Хотя к обсуждаемой на этой ветке теме все сказанное Вами и мною не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Comment: Языковые процессы инерционны, и не успевают за политикой. Поэтому я и говорю о восприятии конкретного носителя. Если говорить об историчности, то в источниках встречается сочетание "в такой-то украине" (без большой буквы). Отторжения у носителя языка не вызывает ни форма "в", ни форма "на" (кстати, в приведенных Вами примерах страны,  которых говорят "на" - острова). Хотя к теме топика это не относится.

Comment: ...страны... "на" - острова. И Русь островной была?

Answer (score 1):

http://dogend.ru/docs/index-421518.html?page=2
Падение редуцированных обусловило появление в древнерусском языке новых ранее невозможных сочетаний согласных звуков. Слабые редуцированные, исчезая, вынуждали к соседству те согласные звуки, которые раньше были отделены друг от друга редуцированными. Упрощение труднопроизносимой группы согласных происходило не обязательно за счет выпадения какого-либо согласного. Внутрь этой группы согласных внедрялся новый гласный лишь для того, чтобы можно было сохранить в произношении все согласные. Так, например, в слове огнь после утраты конечного слабого редуцированного осталась труднопроизносимая группа согласных [огн’], и между [г] и [н] появляется “незаконный” [о]: русск. огонь; то же самое наблюдается в словах: др.-р. оугль, ср. русск. уголь; др.-р. сестръ, ср. русск. сестёр и пр. 
В говорах это явление приобрело больший “размах”: журавель из жоуравль, рубель из роубль, театор из театр, корабель из корабль и т.д.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: В говоре "театор", или у отдельных поэтов?